# Trying to program EPROMs with GQ-4X - 9/10 are failing with a few random bits wrong

Tags: eprom

I have a bunch of old/cheap EPROMs which i am trying to program.
To do this, I am using an GQ-4X.

Starting with blank EPROMs (using a UV eraser thew blank checking them), my hit rate seems to be able 9 fails out of 10, with the failed ones having the odd bits not correct here and there.

I tried burning them quickly, slowly, double write, multiple times. all with the same poor results.

Any clues as to what might be happening? I always thought EPROM where pretty tough but are the cheap chinese ones just bad?
Thanks

Comment: What specific devices are they and just how old? If they are already used, they may have reached the maximum number of programming operations.

Comment: Just buy branded parts from reputable sources.

Comment: If they are good devices with a dozen writes on them already, then they should have 9,988 left to go. Get some known-good name-brand devices from a reputable vendor and try those. If same results, then it's the programmer.

Comment: I don't know much about the CQ-4X. Does it let you set Vcc for blank verification and programming? Are your EPROMs passing blank verification, but failing program verification? Does "cheap chinese ones" mean that they're Chinese manufacturers? Or that you bought them from a source in China and that they could be rejects/defective, counterfeit, etc? ERPOMs don't weren't designed for hundreds or thousands of program/erase cycles. Programming and erase cause oxide damage. Programming the same data multiple times on already programmed devices can encounter a phenomenon Atmel documented as programm